# Populate select dropdown with directory names

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

I want to display folder names of a directory in select dropdown. I am creating a react based app and want to have directory names as options. These names should be populated programmatically as i don't want to update the select options manually every time a new folder gets added to Skins directory. Can anyone help me in figuring out way to achieve this?

```
Skins
|-- default 
|-- skin 1
|-- skin 2
```

options in select dropdown should contain default, skin 1, skin 2,.....

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the question, I think this is what you want.

```
const directory = ['skin1','skin2','skin3']
label for="directory">Choose a directory:</label>
<select name="directory" id="directory">
{directory.map( direct => <option value={direct}>{direct}</option> }}
</select>
```

Comment: I actually dont want to hardcode directory names, i want to get it at run time. For instance if there is an extra folder 'skin4' added in Skins directory then i dont want to goto the directory array and update array manually rather it should be handled programmatically.

Comment: @krishna You need to have data stored somewhere like database or something or else how will you get the directories?

Comment: Isn't there a way to get directories list using some methods? I tried using 'fs.readdirSync(__dirname)' but i get error - Uncaught TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function. So looking for some way to get these directory list..

Comment: you cant use the fs module on the frontend as it is a node js module, but what you can do is to use the fs.readdirSync on the backend and send the list of files to the frontend. I guess that is a way to implement the functionality you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).